# How to make sense of the "data" sent to execute a contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, testnets, abi, calldata

I'm trying to understand the technical details of Ethereum and one thing I can't find any info about is the data to be sent to a contract.

For example, I have a very simple coin flip betting contract on the testnet ethereum chain, and when I execute the "Bet and flip" function on the contract I get (in Mist) a prompt with this "data" that will be sent to the contract:

```
0x25d8dcf2
```

What exactly is the format of this data, and how do I make sense of what each byte means?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Upvoted and hope the ABI info is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, it did, but then raised more questions heh

Comment: No problem about asking more questions as you're familiar with on other Stack Exchange sites!  I tried to give a good answer to the next question you asked.